# Clearing cookies via PHP

Tags: php, cookies

How to clear cookies via php?

I need a php code that will clear the cookies and then refresh the page.

I need some link `<a href=""></a>` and when I click it, the cookies are cleared and page refreshed.

Comment: Do you have specific cookies that you want to clear or are there too many to do each individually?

Comment: I include only one information about language used on the site.
"PHPSESSID"

Comment: Then the answer below by John Conde will work just fine

Comment: This is available in the PHP manual. You could have checked it before you post it here.

Answer (score 2):

[From the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) (which you should be reading *before* coming here to ask for help)

**Example #2 setcookie() delete example**

When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser. Examples follow how to delete cookies sent in previous example:

```
<?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to delete cookies that had an expiration time set.  If you set them with an expire time of 0, that means "the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes)," and the browser will keep them despite receiving delete headers.  (Firefox 13, anyway).

See [php setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)